# Blackberry fieldManager issue 8900 vs. 9550

Tags: layout, blackberry, blackberry-storm, curve, fieldmanager

My buttonset is kind of moving to the right after pushing and closing a new screen.

I added some Buttons to a VerticalFieldManager. Then I added the verticalFieldManager on a horizontalFieldManager to center the buttons.

The problem is on a BB 8900(Curve) is everything fine. On a 9550 (touch screen) it works only when Iam opening the screen the first time. But if I open based on this screen another screen and close the opened screen the buttons are moving to the right. But only on the 9550 ??? On the Curve I can open a new screen and close the new one and it looks like it should. Does someone know this problem?

```
VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldMng = new VerticalFieldManager();      
            ButtonField btnSendAdrViaSMS = new ButtonField("test");
            verticalFieldMng2.add(btnSendAdrViaSMS);
            ButtonField btn2 = new ButtonField("test2");
            verticalFieldMng2.add(btn2);
            ButtonField btn3 = new ButtonField("test2");
            verticalFieldMng2.add(btn3);

            HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);
            horizontalFieldManager.add(verticalFieldMng2);
            add(horizontalFieldManager);
```

For opening the new screen i use

```
    Screen_SendSMS sendSMS = new Screen_SendSMS("",link);
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushModalScreen(sendSMS);
```

And to close the screen i use the regular "back key" of the BB device without overwritting it.

Comment: take the button in hfm and add it to the HFM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats pretty odd, but doesn't surprise me in BB.

UPDATE: After reviewing some of my code to center things, I can say that HorizontalFieldManager, because of the scrolling I guess, has problems to center fields. So when I need to center horizontally I use a VerticalFieldManager, and when I have to center vertically I use an HorizontalFieldManager.

The basic pattern to center fields is this:

```
    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    Field toCenter = new <Field>(DrawStyle.HCENTER | Field.FIELD_HCENTER );
    vfm.add(toCenter);
```

In vertical, it would be:

```
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
    Field toCenter = new <Field>(DrawStyle.VCENTER | Field.FIELD_VCENTER );
    hfm.add(toCenter);
```

You can combine the flags with other style flag with arithmetic OR operator.

In your case you'd have to do this twice: firts with the buttons and the vfm, then with the vfm and hfm.

Comment: Do you have an example for the gridManager?  I following Manager

GridFieldManager headGridMng = new GridFieldManager(1, 4,  GridFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE);

In combination with "headGridMng.setColumnProperty(XX,GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE,XXX);"

and
headGridMng.add(new LabelField("",DrawStyle.LEFT | Field.FIELD_LEFT));